# Raphael zoom goes out of view - add scroll bar

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, raphael, zooming

I have implemented zoom in Raphael using the setViewBox() technique. When I keep zooming the view box becomes bigger than the paper canvas size and the elements on the diagram are no longer visible. Is there a way to add scroll bar around paper so that when elements go out of view, the user can use the scroll bar to see the section of diagram that has gone out of view.

Thanks,
Dikshit

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/138/)** and tell me if it does what you want, or give me comments based on it.

```
var p = Raphael("canvas");
var c = p.circle(150,150,80).attr({fill:'yellow'});

var cx = 300;
var cy = 300;

$('#zi').click(function() {
    cx *= 1.5;
    cy *= 1.5;
    p.setViewBox(0, 0, cx, cy, true);
});

$('#zo').click(function() {
    cx /= 1.5;
    cy /= 1.5;
    p.setViewBox(0, 0, cx, cy, true);
});
```

Comment: This does not work. When we zoom in, we decrease the viewbox size. If I set the div size accordingly, then the visible area reduces further. I tried doing the opposite, i.e. increase the div size when the viewbox reduces but the problem is that the paper width and height remain same and that is the only area visible to user. If I increase the paper width and height, then we don't get the zooming effect.

Comment: Look at the new answer above and tell me what exactly you need or maybe if it does what you are asking

Comment: If I keep zooming out, then only a partial circle is visible. Is there a way to have a scroll bar so that the user can see the complete circle after zooming.